# moving axes while reading h5 file in python(h5py) written in matlab

Tags: python, matlab, data-science, h5py

I am writing h5 file as follows in matlab

```
for loop // Let's assume 4 for now
    fileN = imread(filename);
    im = cat(4, im, fileN);
h5create('data.h5', '/Image', [64 64 3 3], 'Datatype', 'uint8');
h5write('data.h5', '/Image', im);
```

Here, fileN have dimension 64 x 64 x 3
Hence im have dimensions 64 x 64 x 3 x 4

I am reading data.h5 as follows in python

```
hf = h5py.File('./data.h5', 'r')
syn1 = hf['/Image']
```

doing syn1.shape returns 4 x 3 x 64 x 64

Why so? Reading data.h5 in matlab returns correct axes i.e. 64 x 64 x 3 x 4

I have a work-around of using np.moveaxis but was curious if how hd5 file in stored and is there a way in h5py to read dimensions differently (i.e. change the order to the original one while reading itself)

Note that, this reverse ordering rotates image by 90 degree as we are reading in reverse order and that's why I need move axis to make it right.

Comment: MATLAB uses 'F' order, with the last axis changing slowest (outermost).  `numpy` is, by default, order 'C', first is outermost.  `io.loadmat` loads the arrays as order 'F' (which you can see with the `flags` attribute.  `HDF5` uses `C` order, and I think the MATLAB code  translates back and forth (that should be documented).  `h5py` is simply loading the array as it finds it on the file.

Comment: I couldn't file such a documentation. but, Yes. This makes sense.

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/exporting-to-hierarchical-data-format-hdf5-files.html#bqyqs27  - column major versus row major

Comment: I'd use some version of the `numpy` `transpose` to reorder the axes - either the simplest completer reversal, or a partial swap.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj I am swapping partitions in the matlab script now. This will make sure - end use (Python) don't need to do lot of processing as Matlab script will be running only once.

Comment: (There is also a type-o on your third line of code: `[64 64 3 3]` does not match the dimensions you are referring to.)